# Is it possible to search google products (formerly known as www.froogle.com ) using google api?

Tags: java, api, google-product-search

Is it possible to search google products (formerly known as www.froogle.com ) using google api?
I would like to search google products using UPC or EAN or JAN etc GTIN . The response can be XML or JSON .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, it doesn't matter which language you use as you need to submit http requests.
Here is a link to the api: http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/reference-overview.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Hi Gilbert, Using the google products api the GS1 -128 , uPC , ean cannot be be searched. I tried this but it did not give me any output. could you please give me any example where i can substitute my key and get result?

Comment: But this does not produce a specific result. For example if I search in Amazon using their api for a upc=013803123784 , I get a specific camera result. How can i find a specific item when searching using UPC_A, UPC_E, EAN_8 , EAN_13, GS1_128 etc barcodes ? Can we use this foramt of link to achieve a specific result?  https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products/5968952/gid/5103475116874981233?key=key)